# BetterDesktopTool and Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I have setup a keyboard shortcut in BetterDesktopTool that has a sort of mission control view for Windows.

The shortcut is Alt + Tab and I want to map my F3 key to that. But it won't work in Autohotkey

```
#InstallKeybdHook
#SingleInstance force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
#Include Apple Wired Keyboard.ahk
SendMode Input

; --------------------------------------------------------------
; NOTES
; --------------------------------------------------------------
; ! = ALT
; ^ = CTRL

; + = SHIFT
; # = WIN

; media/function keys all mapped to the right option key
F7::SendInput {Media_Prev}
F8::SendInput {Media_Play_Pause}
F9::SendInput {Media_Next}F3F3
; F10::SendInput {Volume_Mute}

; F11::SendInput {Volume_Down}
; F12::SendInput {Volume_Up}

; swap left command/windows key with left alt
LWin::LAlt
LAlt::LWin

; Misc.
F20::WinMinimize A
*F3::SendInput {Alt}{Tab}

; F13-15, Volume
F13::SendInput {Volume_Mute}
F14::SendInput {Volume_Down}F3F3
F15::SendInput {Volume_Up}

;F16-19 Standerd
F16::SendInput {PrintScreen}
F17::SendInput {ScrollLock}
F18::SendInput {Pause}
F19::Run wmplayer
```

I know that my Alt + Tab shortcut works, but it doesn't activate the hotkey for BetterDesktop

Comment: Why do you have a `*` before F3? Does it work without? If not, does `F3::Send, {Alt Down}{Tab Down}{Tab Up}{Alt Up}` work?

Comment: @576i They both work but neither trigger the hotkey to view all windows

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this documentation:

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

Search for "Substitutes for Alt-Tab"